# Remove random string from particular position in file names

Tags: rename

I've downloaded dozen of files from youtube using `youtube-dl`. Nice feature, btw. 
After I searched through them all, I've realized that there are lots of ending with random numbers and letters of different case. Like `video_name_number_of_video_-_the_name_of_episode_part_number-12BUInjas32d1.avi`.

`$ rename -n 's/-.*avi/.avi/i' *.avi` – picks up the first `-` and
 leaves me with `video_name_number_of_video_.avi` name.

**Is there any options to delete this mix of letters and numbers?** I would appreciate any helps. And moreover there are only 13 digits in it.

Added: Someone asked me what exactly do I want. So obviously I want to delete those 13 digits from names of files and live happily the rest of my life. Made the actual question that leads to my aim bold.

Comment: What is exactly form do you want?

Comment: @Gnouc, added some guide for you. Thanks!

Comment: @jasonwryan, nope. That doesn't help me a lot. Because as I said those 13 digits are different all the time. They are completely random. I can't specify what to rename in `rename` command. But I can say between what we should rename. And another "but", `rename` picks the first `-` in name, not the second `-`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rename -n 's/-[^-]*\.avi$/.avi/i' ./*
```

The idea being to match `-` followed by a sequence (`*`) of non-dash characters (`[^-]`) followed by `.avi` at the end of the string (`$`). `-.*avi` would match from the first `-` to the last `avi`.

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # in ~/.zshrc as it's a damn useful command

zmv -n '(#i)(*)(-*)(.avi)' '$1$3'
```

`(#i)` for case insensitive globbing.

Comment: Dang it, you beat me to it by about 20 seconds. Mine is a bit more specific, however.

Comment: Works perfect for me. Thanks a lot. Could you give some explanation to this, or some helpful links to understand how this magic happened?

Answer (score 1):

I assume those are YouTube video IDs. You can remove them by using a regular expression like:

```
s/-[^-.]{13}\.avi$/.avi/
```

Breaking this down into its parts, we have:

- `-` - just a hyphen
- `[^-.]{13}` - exactly 13 characters which are neither hyphens nor periods
- `\.avi` - matches simply ".avi" in the file name
- `$` anchor at the end of the string (file name)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. Put all your file name in a text file, i.e filename.txt:

> video_name_number_of_video_-_the_name_of_episode_part_number-12BUInjas32d1.avi
>   video_name_number_of_video_-_the_name_of_episode_part_number-12BUInjas32d2.avi
>   video_name_number_of_video_-_the_name_of_episode_part_number-12BUInjas32d3.avi

Write a script:

```
#/bin/bash -

while IFS= read -r line 
do
    mv -- "$line" "${line%-*}.avi"
done < filename.txt
```

Comment: Instead of writing a script, you can use `qmv` from the [renameutils](http://www.nongnu.org/renameutils/).